# Ionic serve / ionic run not reflecting changes

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, service-worker

Both ionic serve and ionic run are not reflecting any of my latest changes. ionic serve is showing them from a few hours ago, and ionic run is showing them from about an hour later. Since then, I've discarded all my changes, and created a new branch from the parent--yet it's still showing those same versions from a few hours ago on the first branch. In short, there's code showing up that I don't have in any files in this, or any, branch. And no uncommitted changes.

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.2
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
ios-deploy version: 1.9.0
ios-sim version: 5.0.8
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.10.1
Xcode version: Xcode 8.3.1 Build version 8E1000a
```

I've tried things including `ionic state restore` and `ionic state reset` as well as removing and adding platforms back manually.

Also, this is what shows up in my console currently:

```
Static file server running @ http://localhost:8000/index.html
CTRL + C to shut down

200 /service-worker.js
```

Whereas it previously displayed a list of html, css, etc. requests when the page loaded. Currently, I can make it work as expected by unregistering and removing all ServiceWorkers at chrome://serviceworker-internals/ and chrome://inspect/#service-workers

Comment: Clear your cache on Safari

Comment: @SouravDas -- using Chrome. Cleared cache but no change.

Comment: Have you updated your ionic CLI, npm install -g ionic

Comment: Yeah--no change.

Answer (score 2):

@stephen, it's been some time now, but I faced a similar issue before. Turns out I had registered the service worker that ships with projects created with the CLI, check your index.html and see if the lines that register the service worker are commented out. If they are you may be having a different problem, if they aren't and you didn't plan to use a service worker, comment them out again, and on your browser (you said chrome), after running ionic serve, open "Inspect" (Ctrl+Shift+I), go to the "Application" tab - "Service Workers" and unregister it.

This happens because the service worker that ships with new projects created using the cli will cache all resources, next time you update your code the browser will load the previous version, that's why you don't see the changes.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Open the developer console, right click on the button to reload the page and click on empty cache and reload in a forced way (Last option).

[image: Example]